# Showing multiplicity between subclasses of an inheritance and another class out of inheritance

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Consider the following class diagram.[image]

I need to satisfy two conditions in my model:

1-`Node` can only have 1 `cutted Line`, but it can have 0 or many `Line` instances.

2- A node comes from either a `cutted Line`, or a `Line` (*but not both*)

I first, draw the bellow domain model. But then i made my mind to reduce the complexity by an inheritance of `Edge`.[image]

It seems that the first solution covers the second requirement, but it does not cover the multiplicity. Unfortunately the second solution covers the multiplicity but not the second condition.
How can I draw it to satisfy both conditions?
**Update:**
I finally, come up with this solution:
[image]

But i am not sure if it is true or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That situation is called a ***derived union***.

> A `Node` comes from either a `CuttedLine`, or a `Line` (but not both)

The association between `Line` and `Node` (or `CuttedLine`) ***subsets*** the association between `Edge` and `Node`, because if a `Node` comes from a `Line` (or `CuttedLine`) then:

- it comes from an `Edge`
- that `Edge` is of type `Line` (or `CuttedLine`)

Moreover, the association between `Edge` and `Node` is ***derived*** from the associations between `Line` and `Node` and between `CuttedLine` and `Node`, because if a `Node` comes from an `Edge`, then it comes from a `CuttedLine` or comes from a `Line`. UML defines a derived union as *"as the union of all of the Properties that are constrained to subset it."*

Since a `Node` comes from a single `Edge` (the cardinality is 1) and the generalization is *disjoint*, it follows that a `Node` comes **either** from a `Line` or a `CuttedLine`, but not both. (The union of two distinct sets has a single element if one of the sets is empty and the other has a single element.)

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply go with the 2nd picture as it describes the model as intended. You can still add a `Edge` class as general form of `Line` and `CuttedLine`. Just that it does not have connectors to `Node`.

Alternatively you can use the first one and add constraints which explain the different multiplicities.